# Fancy menu, looking like a folder

Tags: html, css

I need to create a menu, looking like a folder, but have not enough skill. I have the concept art of the idea.
[concept art](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEkxt.jpg)

The menu has 8 pages with text and images. Each page has it’s own mark. When you hover it, it becomes wider, like the red one. When you click it, it changes the page with content and the previous opened mark becomes shorter. Each mark must contain the icon.

Here I have the code, which I was trying to use as a reference

```css
.flex-container { display: flex; }

.darkblock {
   background-color:rgb(var(--gray-monochrome));
   color:rgb(var(--white-monochrome));
   padding: 0.01rem 1rem;
   margin: 0.5rem 0 0.5rem 0.25rem;
   box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 0.3rem rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}

/* linkblocks */
.linkblock { position: relative;}
.linkblock a:hover { opacity: 0.4;}
.linkblock a { color: rgba(0,0,0,0);position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 5; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;  transition: 0.3s; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);}

/* top nav boxes */
.banner { height: 15rem; }
.topnav {
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
    width: -moz-available;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
    transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
    height: 3rem;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
    background-color: rgb(var(--gray-monochrome));
    color: rgb(var(--white-monochrome));
    padding: 0.01rem 1rem;
    margin: -0.25px 0 0.5rem 0.25rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 0.3rem rgb(0 0 0 / 25%);
}
.topnav:hover { height: 5rem; }
.banner .darkblock { margin-bottom: 0; text-align: center; padding-bottom: 0.8rem; padding-top: 0.8rem;}
.topnav a { background: rgb(255,255,255);
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 95%); }
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="darkblock">
    <p>A lot of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="topnav linkblock" style="background:#537496;">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="topnav linkblock" style="background:#43846b;">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="topnav linkblock" style="background:#d16537;">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have no success at all right now. Could anybody help with it, if it’s not hard for you?

Comment: Post your entire code, including HTML, CSS and JS (if any).

Comment: I did it now! You can check it out